# core plot yAxis Labels scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-plot

I have plotted a Bar Graph using core-plot.

I have enabled scrolling in X-Axis direction. The problem that I am facing is that when I scroll the labels on the Y-Axis also start to scroll

[image: this is the image without scrolling]

[image: This is what happens when I scroll]

The Y-Axis gets hidden,I want to hide the labels on Y-Axis also when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the y-axis in place by positioning it using the `axisConstraints` rather than the `orthogonalCoordinate`. Set it a fixed distance from the edge of the graph and it won't move when the graph scrolls.

If you want the labels to disappear when the user scrolls past a certain point, use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space and hide the labels when the plot ranges go outside the desired range.

Comment: I am using this delegate method to hide the labels
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement

The problem with this is if I am dragging to positive direction the value of displacement becomes positive because of which the labels get shown again. is there a delegate method which will tell me the absolute position with respect to the origin.

Comment: Try `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` This method is called any time the plot ranges change.

Comment: hey Eric. I tried -plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate: . The problem with this method is that when I do newRange.location it gives me values but the last value I get is always 0. Due to this I am not able to calculate how much and which side the graph has moved.

Comment: Are you checking the `coordinate` parameter, too? Make sure you're looking at `CPTCoordinateX`.

Answer (score 0):

```
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
 axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```